# Binary Visual Diff Tool for MacOS X

Tags: macos, diff, hex-editor

This might already be answered, but I did not find an answer that really matched my needs. I'm looking for a visual diff tool that can diff binary files. It was also OK if it was integrated into a hexeditor.

Comment: There is an answer for that on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871702/is-there-any-graphical-binary-diff-tool-for-mac-os-x